# Selecting columns using query statement in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe. Each point is combined with 'n' class points of each class, and each combination has a value of 0 or 1. 
Now for each point, I want to get the class which has the highest number of '0'.
Output :
Pt.1 - a
Pt.2 -b

I have tried with hash table, but its being a bit cumbersome. What can be an elegant pandas dataframe query for this?

```
+------+-------+-------+--+--+--+
| Pt.  | class | value |  |  |  |
+------+-------+-------+--+--+--+
| Pt.1 | a     |     0 |  |  |  |
| Pt.1 | a     |     0 |  |  |  |
| Pt.1 | a     |     1 |  |  |  |
| Pt.1 | b     |     0 |  |  |  |
| Pt.1 | b     |     1 |  |  |  |
| pt.1 | b     |     1 |  |  |  |
| Pt.2 | a     |     1 |  |  |  |
| Pt.2 | a     |     1 |  |  |  |
| Pt.2 | a     |     1 |  |  |  |
| Pt.2 | b     |     0 |  |  |  |
| Pt.2 | b     |     0 |  |  |  |
| Pt.2 | b     |     0 |  |  |  |
|      |       |       |  |  |  |
+------+-------+-------+--+--+--+
```

Comment: Why is the `r` tag here?

Comment: because dataframe operations are similar in r and python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only `0` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then count by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) which sorts output, so is necessary seelct first `index` value by indexing:

```
df = (df[df['value'] == 0].groupby('Pt.')['class']
                          .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
                          .reset_index(name='top1'))
print (df)
    Pt. top1
0  Pt.1    a
1  Pt.2    b
```

Similar alternative with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering:

```
df = (df.query("value == 0")
        .groupby('Pt.')['class']
        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
        .reset_index(name='top1'))
print (df)
    Pt. top1
0  Pt.1    a
1  Pt.2    b
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!